# Generating Random numbers and printing "Done!" if they fall within a range in C

Tags: c, loops, random, srand

Sorry if this question has been answered elsewhere, I did search but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Anyway, I am stuck on a university homework problem, the problem asks for me to create a script that randomly generates numbers between 0-99 and prints the number on a new line each time, and if the number just printed falls within the range 68-74 it should then print Done! on the next line and exit the script.

I was given a template with most of the code already done for me, it looks as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    /**
     * Your solution must start from below this point. No code modifications WHATSOEVER are allowed ABOVE this point!
     */


    /**
     * Your solution must have finished by this point. No code modifications WHATSOEVER are allowed BELOW this point!
     */
    return 0;
}

int getRandInt() {
    return rand() % 100;
}
```

Anyway after a lot of messing around I finally got it to print a list random numbers rather than 1 random number infinitely. I did this using:

```
do
    printf ("%d\n", getRandInt());
while (getRandInt());
```

I tried plugging in things like:

```
do
    printf ("%d\n", getRandInt());
while (getRandInt() <68);
```

to see if it would at least only print random integers less than 68, but this just makes it print only 1 or 2 random numbers (sometimes with greater values than 68) instead of the huge list the previous code block prints.

Am I calling the right function? Should I be using a Do While loop? How do I set a range of numbers for the loop to exit and print "Done!"? Obviously I can't edit the code outside of the comments.

I am very new to coding and would appreciated any assistance with this problem.

Comment: How many experiments have you done?

Comment: A lot, I've been plugging in different things all morning.

Comment: Now let's hope your professor doesn't come here too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a another integer variable and call the function inside the loop. So every time the return value will be stored in that variable, use that variable for condition checking.

Try the following code snippet-

```
/**
 * Your solution must start from below this point. No code modifications WHATSOEVER are       allowed ABOVE this point!
 */
    int ret;
    do{
            ret = getRandInt();
            printf("%d\n",ret);

    }while(!(ret >= 68 && ret <= 74));

    printf("Done!\n");
/**
 * Your solution must have finished by this point. No code modifications WHATSOEVER are allowed BELOW this point!
 */
```

From the above code, when the number falls between 68 to 74 it will print `Done!` and exit the loop. If not (`!(ret >= 68 && ret <= 74)`) it will continue and execute the loop till a number falls between 68 to 74.

Comment: Thank you, this work perfectly! And most importantly I understand why it works.

I was trying to declare another variable but I wasn't doing it in the loop so I kept getting the same random number repeating. I also didn't know about the "&&" command. 
Thank you once more and thanks to everyone else who commented, it is much appreciated!

Comment: @PermanentWaves `&&` this is logical and operator. when the both left and right side conditions are true it will return true.

Comment: The `if` condition with `exit` is pointless: You could move the `Done!` printing after the `while` condition.

Comment: @Sathish I remember && now from MATLAB, and I see someone else wrote a script using 
     while(r > 74 || r < 68);
so that's just DeMorgan's law right? instead of being "while ( everything NOT inside this range)", it's "while (everything outside this range)"

Comment: @PermanentWaves Ya. you are right!. you can find lot of ways like that!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `getRandInt()` you get a new random value. This means that you are checking the condition in the while loop with a different random number than you are printing.

To fix this, you need to get a random value and store it, and then do the comparison. You can solve this using many different types of loops including do/while.

Also note that it is good style to use parents with your do statement:

```
do {
    // code here.
} while ( ... );
```

Since you have identified this as homework I'll leave the help there, unless you have other questions.

Comment: so should i declare another int like "number" and then do something like: 
    int number = getRandInt()
and then call the number int in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are just confused with how to write the condition in `do while` loop.

Try this code it will work!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int getrandom_no()
{
    return rand() % 100;
}

int main(void) {
    int r=0;

    srand(time(NULL)); /* To use rand function you must use srand first */
    do 
    {
        r = getrandom_no();
        printf("%d\n",r);
    }while(r > 74 || r < 68);
    puts("Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This script works but I am not allowed to edit any code outside of the comments. Thank you anyway, as the more examples I have to study the better my understanding is.